# Drupal Commons packages or ordinary package?

Tags: drupal, social-media

I have to create a website with social network features and I have a question if I am using normal Drupal core package: is it comfortable for creating a social networking featured website. I heard about Drupal Commons; is that better than this?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this using various modules available in Drupal.

Following is the list of modules, I would need to make a social networking site:

```
-guestbook ( equivalent to comments on profile or scraps )
-image, inline, shazamgaller: to be able to add images inline and create photo gallaries.
-invite ( allows to become member by invitation only )
-OG ( gives you groups or communities )
-cck ( let you make any type of content )
-private message ( and chat, if you want )
-mysite
-nodeprofiles (http://groups.drupal.org/profiles-as-nodes)
-event
-buddylist
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest for Drupal Commons - https://www.acquia.com/products-services/drupal-commons-social-business-software/benefits. Its a proven Drupal distribution for Social Networking sites. Drupal commons has best implementations of Social Networking features enlisted below:

- Groups Messaging
- Statuses
- Questions
- User Profiles
- Polls
- Group
- Activity
- Email notification
- Group Subscription
- and lot many

Most benefiting factor of using Commons would be you dont have spend any time (on development nad testing) of basic social networking features. Distribution is quite stable as its maintained by Acquia.